# Find cell value in a different tab

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I would really appreciate some help with the code below. I haven't had much luck trying to make it work the way I want it to. What I'm trying to do is find the value entered in tab 1 cell "K2" in tab 2. If value exist in tab 2 it will select the value and does some code, and then check if another cell exist with the text string. What I can't figure out is creating the loop that will find all cells that have the text string I'm trying to find. Thanks in advance!

```
Sub test()
Dim SearchRng As range
Dim FindVar As Variant
Dim find As Variant
Dim EndNum As Long
Dim r As range

    Set Final = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab 1")
    Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab 2")

    EndNum = WS.range("A1").End(xlDown).row

    Set SearchRng = WS.range("A1:A" & CStr(EndNum))
    Set FindVar = SearchRng.find(range("K2").Value)

    For Each r In FindVar
        If Not FindVar Is Nothing Then
            WS.Activate
            FindVar.Activate
            'my code
            Else
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in the event you weren't aware, you do not need to `.Activate` or `.Select` these ranges - all this does is *significantly* slow down your code and make your screen do strange things... But this may have been done for testing purposes, which is fine.

Also, you should add `Option Explicit` to the top of your modules as you never declared your worksheet objects. I did this for you.

You can use the `.FindNext` method to do what you are asking.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, Final As Worksheet
    Set Final = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab 1")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab 2")

    Dim EndNum As Long
    EndNum = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim sToFind As String, rngFind As Range, addrStart
    sToFind = ws.Range("K2").Value

    With ws.Range("A1:A" & EndNum)
        Set rngFind = .find(sToFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
            addrStart = rngFind.Address
            Do
                ws.Activate
                rngFind.Select
                'my code  
                Set rngFind = .FindNext(rngFind)
            Loop While Not rngFind Is Nothing And rngFind.Address <> addrStart
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

The reason that your `For Each r In FindVar` didn't work was that the `FindVar` was a `1x1` range.